# How do we get user request, response, and request-id along with process-id in spring-boot logging using logback.xml and MDC?

Tags: java, logging, mdc, spring-logback

I have been trying to create a *logback.xml* logging pattern for my *spring-boot* project in which I can get some requirements.

I want to print data in logging pattern (such as *process-id*, *request-id*, user request data for a particular API request, user response for the same, etc. ) using *MDC* but I couldn't find any solution about how *MDC* communicates with `logback.xml` and inserts the required value.

I am new in *spring-boot* and Java development; kindly suggest me some solution or ideas.

Comment: Made a few grammatical improvements, since incorrect grammar is not recommended. This is not a casual chat room. To further improve your question, you can provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values in the MDC using put

```
MDC.put("process-id", "1");
```

And then you define a log pattern that uses these values with %X

```
%X{process-id}
```

For example you can define the pattern in the application.properties:

```
logging.pattern.console=%-4r [%thread] %-5level %X{process-id} - msg%n
```

Or in the logback.xml

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout>
      <Pattern>%-4r [%thread] %-5level %X{process-id} - msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>       
</appender>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir, but i am not aware of how MDC works, does spring boot support MDC inherently or do we have to configure it with project by injecting externally?

Comment: No this is part of the logger like logback or Log4j. You don't have to do anything. Simply use MDC.put Read more about MDC in the documentation: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi,                                                                                I have one Solution, Apache-Log4j given one class is ThreadContext. with the help of this class we can add/remove data in MDC context.

please follow the below steps :

- Create one Servlet Filter or Spring Given Filter.
- import ThreadContext calss from  'org.apache.logging.log4j' package.
- And add '[%X]' in log pattern
- please follow below code.

  ```
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

   @Component
   public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
   response, Object handler) {

           RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

          long pid = Long.valueOf(bean.getName().split("@")[0]);

          ThreadContext.put("process-id", pid);
          ThreadContext.put("request-id", request.getParameter("requestid"));  //etc.. add Something..


  return true;
  }

    @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
      throws Exception {

  ThreadContext.put("response", "add here");  //etc.. response.getSomething

  ThreadContext.clearMap(); //this remove all in the MDC 
  }

  }
  ```

  Or,
  Instead of this, you can use ServletFilter also.

Comment: can you please explain me how  ThreadContext and MDC is similar ?

Comment: I don't know any briefly. but when I am using it is maintain like an application context.we can push the data into MDC context and we can clear the context, until  clear the MDC it doesn't remove from context.I hope you understand.

Comment: try with the above code once.you will get to know what is happening in the inside. :)